# Racket sequences in data/collection vs built-in sequences

Tags: racket, generic-programming

I've been playing with some of the interfaces in `data/collection` and I'm loving it so far. Having generic interfaces to different Racket collections like lists, streams, and sequences, is really handy -- especially given the diversity of interfaces to such types otherwise (`list-*`, `vector-*`, `string-*`, `stream-*`, `sequence-*`, ... !).

But do these interfaces play well with the built-in sequences in Racket? Specifically, I'm running into this error:

```
(require data/collection)
(take 10 (in-cycle '(1 2 3)))
```

=>

```
; take: contract violation
;   expected: sequence?
;   given: #<sequence>
;   in: the 2nd argument of
;       (-> natural? sequence? sequence?)
;   contract from: 
;       <pkgs>/collections-lib/data/collection/sequence.rkt
;   blaming: top-level
;    (assuming the contract is correct)
;   at: <pkgs>/collections-lib/data/collection/sequence.rkt:53.3
```

The function `in-cycle` returns a built-in "sequence," while the polymorphic `take` provided by `data/collections` expects its own special sequence interface.

In this particular case I could manually define a stream to replace the built-in `in-cycle`, something like:

```
(define (in-cycle coll [i 0])
  (stream-cons (nth coll (modulo i (length coll)))
               (in-cycle coll (add1 i))))
```

... which works, but there are an [awful lot of built-in sequences defined](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sequences.html) so I'm wondering if there's a better, perhaps standard/recommended way to handle this. That is, can we take advantage of all the built-in sequences in terms of the sequences defined in data/collection, the same way the latter wraps other existing sequences like lists and streams?

Comment: To be clear, there's [`cycle`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/collections/collections-api.html#%28def._%28%28lib._data%2Fcollection..rkt%29._cycle%29%29) which is the counterpart of `in-cycle`. So in this particular case, you can just use it instead.

Comment: The sequences on that page seem to mirror some of the ones on the one I linked originally, so that should be a good start, thanks! There are many still missing, like `in-hash`, `in-port`, all the collection-based ones. Of course it would be ideal if builtin sequences could be seamlessly treated as generic sequences to preclude this redundancy, but presumably there's a good reason that can't be done..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After working through it some more, I think I have a better understanding of sequences in Racket and in `data/collection`. I'll take a crack at summarizing all the points that have been brought up in other answers and comments, and also include my own learnings.

Racket sequences, that is, the ones that come built-in, are intended to be a [generic interface](https://blog.racket-lang.org/2012/11/generics.html) to all ordered collections, the same way that you can use `dict-*` functions to work with any dictionary type including hashes. In addition, there are also many handy utilities that provide builtin sequences to make it easy to work with ordered data in different scenarios, like a sequence of elements taken from a collection, or a sequence of inputs received on some input port, or a sequence of key-value pairs taken from a dictionary -- this last of which isn't inherently an "ordered" collection, but which can be treated as one by using the built-in sequence interface.

So we can think of builtin sequences as having a twofold purpose:

1. being a uniform interface for ordered data, and
2. making it convenient to work with sequences in diverse scenarios by providing a natural sequence interface implementation in each case.

Now, although builtin sequences are intended to be a uniform interface for ordered collections in theory, in practice they are not especially usable for this purpose due to their verbosity, e.g. `sequence-take` and `sequence-length` instead of just the `take` and `length` that we'd use for lists.

`data/collection` sequences address this shortcoming by virtue of their names being short and canonical, like `take` instead of `sequence-take`. In addition, these sequences also provide [drop-in replacements](https://docs.racket-lang.org/collections/collections-api.html) for many of the sequence utilities provided by builtin sequences, like `cycle` and `naturals` instead of `in-cycle` and `in-naturals`, along with a generic `in` function to derive lazy versions of any sequence for use in iteration (like `(in (naturals))`). These `data/collection` versions are generally more "well-behaved" by virtue of being immutable, which builtin sequences do not guarantee. As a result, `data/collection` sequences can be thought of as a *replacement* for builtin sequences in many cases, largely taking over the first of the two purposes of builtin sequences.

**That is, in places where you are dealing with sequences, consider using `data/collection` sequences *instead* of builtin sequences, not as a way to *work with* builtin sequences.**

On point (2), however, the following are the types that are currently treatable as data/collection sequences:

- lists
- immutable hash tables
- immutable vectors
- immutable hash sets
- immutable dictionaries
- streams

([source](https://docs.racket-lang.org/collections/collections-api.html#%28def._%28%28lib._data%2Fcollection..rkt%29._gen~3asequence%29%29))

That's plenty, but there are still more scenarios in which a common-sense sequence could be derived. For any such cases that are not covered above, the builtin sequence utilities are still useful, like `in-hash` and `in-port` which have no analogues in `data/collection` sequences. In general there are many cases in which we can easily derive a builtin sequence (see the utilities [here](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sequences.html)) but not a `data/collection` sequence. In these special cases, we could simply convert the builtin sequence so obtained into a stream via `sequence->stream` and then use it via the simpler `data/collection` sequence interface, since streams are treatable as sequences of either type.

Comment: Marking this as accepted, please feel free to add to it or make corrections as needed (esp. those who provided other answers which are integrated into this one)

Answer (score 2):

As @Sorawee Porncharoenwase mentioned, you could use `cycle` from `data/collection` instead of the built-in `in-cycle`.

You can also apply `sequence->stream` to results of `in-cycle`, 
since a Racket's stream is both a built-in and `data/collection` sequence. For example,

```
(take 10 (sequence->stream (in-cycle '(1 2 3 4))))
```

Comment: Did not know about `cycle` and the other sequences there -- that should be a good start. Converting builtin sequences into streams in order to use generic sequences somewhat nullifies the whole benefit of generics, so that would be more of a last resort.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit tricky. This expression `(in-cyle '(1 2 3))` evaluates to a Racket sequence.
Racket sequences are different from "generic sequences" (see docs for data/collection).

When you require `take` from `data/collection`, you get the `take` that expects a generic collection, so

```
#lang racket
(require data/collection)
(take 10 (in-cycle '(1 2 3)))
```

will give you an error.

The docs says that the following builtin datatypes work as collections:

- lists
- immutable hash tables
- immutable vectors
- immutable hash sets
- immutable dictionaries
- streams

So we need to convert the sequence `(in-cycle '(1 2 3))` into one of the above.
The obvious choice as @capfredf mentions is `sequence->stream`.

```
#lang racket
(require data/collection)
(take 10 (sequence->stream (in-cycle '(1 2 3))))
```

This works as expected.

Comment: If all of those builtin datatypes can be treated as generic sequences, I wonder why builtin sequences themselves (like `(in-cycle)`) cannot likewise be treated as generic sequences... any idea what the difficulty there might be?

Comment: No idea, but perhaps Alexis does?

Comment: @mindthief Sequences are not immutable, but streams are. Sequences are basically mutable iterators/generators, while `sequence->stream` reifies the sequence into an immutable datatype.

Comment: @mindthief Put another way, `data/collection` assumes that calling `first` multiple times on the same thing is both idempotent and always returns the same value, but this would not necessarily be the case for Racket sequences.

Comment: Aha, that makes a lot of sense. Is that also why some `in-*` sequences return sequences while others return streams, the former when the types are mutable and the latter when they are immutable? Hm, just checked and this doesn't appear to be the case -- `in-hash` returns a sequence and so does `in-mutable-hash`...

Comment: Marking this as accepted since the discussion gives some insight into why the original question does not have a good answer.

Comment: At the same time, @AlexisKing I don't really understand what makes immutability a requirement for generic sequences, so if you're able to add any color there that'd be helpful!

Comment: @mindthief Mostly just that iteration over mutable sequences is full of gotchas and complications, and making all sequences immutable dramatically simplifies the API while still being very useful.